# Using Microsoft.Data.Common in ASP.NET vNext app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am playing around with ASP.NET vNext. Currently, I am just trying to connect to a Sql Server database using `[DataCommon][1]`. I am having problems adding the package to my project. Currently, my project.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Data.Common":"1.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "commands": {
    "run": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {},
    "aspnetcore50": {}
  }
}
```

When I execute `kpm restore` from the command-line, I get an error that says:

```
Unable to locate Microsoft.Data.Common >= 1.0.0-beta1
```

How do I add this package to my project? How do I find the versions of the packages? In the Node world, I know I can look at bower.json to identify the version of a package. However, in this NuGet world, I'm not sure where the package version is specified. I was expecting it to be in the [NuGet.config](https://github.com/aspnet/DataCommon/blob/dev/NuGet.Config) file.

How do I connect to a database using Microsoft.Data.Common in an ASP.NET vNext app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the wrong version of the Microsoft.Data.Common library. If you attempt to add it via the Visual Studio 2015 preview, you'll notice the latest version that the latest version that works is 0.1.0.0-alpha-build-0137. For that reason, you need to have the following:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "Microsoft.Data.Common":"0.1.0.0-alpha-build-0137"
  },
  "commands": {
    "run": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {},
    "aspnetcore50": {}
  }
}
```

That should work for you.